# Unable To Connect to External Data Source Via EBS instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, configuration, database-connection, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have a database server hosted on Jealastic PaaS and our java application created in EC2 via EBS. I'm connecting to the Jelastic DB locally via Mysql Workbench and it's working properly. But, while connecting via EBS it's giving the following exception.

> I'm not sure from how/where it's replacing the Jelastic Connection String with the following Internal IP 192.168.1.201.I've checked the EC2 instance's security group and they're all open for outbound traffic.

```
8879 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'USER_NAME'@'192.168.1.201' (using password: YES))
Mar 12, 2018 9:25:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.idsk.optportal.util.OPTGlobalContext
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'optuser'@'192.168.1.201' (using password: YES)); nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'optuser'@'192.168.1.201' (using password: YES))
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertJdbcAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:424)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:410)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:339)
    at com.idsk.optportal.dao.catalog.CategoryDaoHibernate.getAllCategories(CategoryDaoHibernate.java:304)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invoke(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at com.idsk.optportal.util.logging.LoggingInterceptor.invoke(LoggingInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy50.getAllCategories(Unknown Source)
    at com.idsk.optportal.service.company.OPTCompanyService.getAllCategories(OPTCompanyService.java:2065)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invoke(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at com.idsk.optportal.util.logging.LoggingInterceptor.invoke(LoggingInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.getAllCategories(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.getAllCategories(Unknown Source)
    at com.idsk.optportal.util.OPTGlobalContext.contextInitialized(OPTGlobalContext.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5632)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1015)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:991)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1296)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:2038)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'USER_NAME'@'192.168.1.201' (using password: YES))
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:855)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:540)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1700)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1715)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
    at com.idsk.optportal.dao.catalog.CategoryDaoHibernate$1.doInHibernate(CategoryDaoHibernate.java:306)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'USER_NAME'@'192.168.1.201' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3996)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1284)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2137)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:352)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:284)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:290)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:877)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:851)
    ... 74 more
```